# Need to fetch data from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name `reffer` which containing record given below MySQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE `reffer` (
      `reffer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `register_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `reffer_by` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `reffer`
    --

    INSERT INTO `reffer` (`reffer_id`, `seller_id`, `register_id`, `level`, `reffer_by`) VALUES
    (1, 462, 580, 1, 462),
    (2, 462, 581, 2, 580),
    (3, 462, 582, 2, 580),
    (4, 580, 583, 2, 580),
    (5, 462, 584, 3, 583),
    (6, 462, 585, 4, 584),
    (7, 462, 586, 5, 585),
    (8, 462, 587, 6, 586);
```

I need a mysql query or php function to get all the users which is reffered by register_id = 580.

1. In this image 580 is reffered by 462 and 581,582,583 all these reffered by 580 and 584 is reffered by 583 , 585 is reffered by 586 and so on.
2. 582 has no child found.
3. 583 has 584,585,586,587
4. 580 has 581 to 5587

I need this type of query that find record like 2,3,4 point.

I have tried mysql query but not getting same result.

```
select * from reffer where reffer_by = 582
```

But not getting correct result.

I have also tried it for nested function in php like :

```
function reffered($user_id=null,$refferedData=null){
   if(count($refferedData) == 0 || empty($refferedData)){
    $refferedData = array();
   }

   $sql_refer = mysql_query("select register_id from reffer where reffer_by = ".$user_id);
   $rows_reffer = mysql_fatch_assoc($sql_refer);
   $count_reffer = mysql_num_rows($sql_refer);
   if($count_reffer != 0){
    $refferedData[] = $rows_reffer['register_id'];

    reffered($rows_reffer['register_id'],$refferedData);
   }else{
       return $refferedData;
   }

}
```

Comment: can you post your table structure along with sample data

Comment: Yes Give me a min

Comment: I have attached image did you need csv or sql?

Comment: Satya Sir, Please check again. I have added mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issues in your code, I'm going to go ahead and rewrite your function and use comments to explain my thoughts and the fixes.

```
function reffered($user_id=null,$refferedData=null){
     // as $refferedData defaults to a non-array (null) we 
     // should check if it is an array, then if it's empty 
     if(!is_array($refferedData) || empty($refferedData)){
          $refferedData = array();
     }

     // your original code was NOT sql injection safe (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
     // this code forces the user input to be a safe integer
     $query = sprintf('select register_id from reffer where reffer_by = %d', $user_id);

     // this assumes we've already got a valid mysql_connect() running somewhere
     $sql_refer = mysql_query($query);

     // we should check if we have results FIRST before running the fetch_assoc
     if(mysql_num_rows($sql_refer)) {
          // we loop through the results and add register_id to the array stack,
          // while passing in the register_id to the next recursion
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_refer)){
               $refferedData[] = $row['register_id'];
               $refferedData = refferedData($row['register_id'], $refferedData);
          }
     }
    return $refferedData;
}
```

This code *is* untested, as recursion such as this can be very dangerous.  If you have any questions or a better example of what you're trying to accomplish, I would love to offer more help.

Comment: Hello trolboy ,

**In this mysql 580 is reffered by 462 and 581,582,583 all these reffered by 580 and 584 is reffered by 583 , 585 is reffered by 586 and so on.**
**582 has no child found.**
**583 has 584,585,586,587**
**580 has 581 to 5587** Is there any way to fetch record from mysql

Comment: 580 should get you: 2,3,4 and then call lookups against 2,3,4 for  which there is no data shown.  I'm assuming from your edited question that your dataset goes all the way up to id 5587, but without seeing concrete examples, it is hard for me to say.